# Transitioning from a state containing an ng-grid object is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid, angular-ui-router

In my AngularJS app, I use ui-router for navigation and ng-grid to display data. Things work fine until I transition from a state containing a grid to any other state. This is the corresponding template:

```
<div ng-controller="MainUserController" class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When transitioning away from this state to any other state, I log the following error flow:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'off' of null
at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (http://127.0.0.1:9000/bower_components/ng-grid/build/ng-grid.debug.js:1008:31)
at HTMLDivElement.jQuery.event.dispatch (http://127.0.0.1:9000/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js:4624:9)
at HTMLDivElement.elemData.handle (http://127.0.0.1:9000/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js:4292:46)
at Object.jQuery.event.trigger (http://127.0.0.1:9000/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js:4533:12)
at jQuery.fn.extend.triggerHandler (http://127.0.0.1:9000/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js:5241:24)
at removePatch [as remove] (http://127.0.0.1:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:2213:21)
at Object.leave (http://127.0.0.1:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4079:17)
at Object.leave (http://127.0.0.1:9000/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js:2668:49)
at cleanupLastView (http://127.0.0.1:9000/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js:2717:22)
at http://127.0.0.1:9000/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js:2739:13
```

Removing ng-grid="gridOptions" solves the problem hence why I am assuming my conflict arises between ui-router and ng-grid.

Any insights?

EDIT: this is how I declare gridOptions.

```
        $scope.gridOptions = {
        data: 'data',
        plugins: [new ngGridFlexibleHeightPlugin()],
        showSelectionCheckbox: true,
        columnDefs: [{ field: 'username', displayName: 'Name', width: "**" },
            { field: 'email', displayName: 'Email', width: "**"}]
    };
```

Comment: have you tried using another version of ng-grid?, try the latest version , //cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-grid/2.0.8/ng-grid.debug.js

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, Alex Choroshin. It's a good point but unfortunately the error remains.

Comment: The part of the code in UI Router referenced in the stack trace is responsible for removing DOM elements, which ng-grid appears not to like. This is kind of a shot in the dark, but try making a controller at a higher scope with a button that does `angular.element("[ng-controller=MainUserController]").remove()` and seeing if that triggers the same error. Also, what is the value of `gridOptions`?

Comment: @NateAbele You are right, adding your button did remove the error however it does not remove the grid from my view when transiting to another state. I have also edited my question above with the definition of `gridOptions`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an open [issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/issues/1142) with this error regarding the conflict of ng-grid and ui-router and it seems that [Herve Prot](https://github.com/hepr) found a fix, I haven't tested it yet.

line 952 in build/ng-grid.js:

```
   grid.$topPanel.on('$destroy', function() {
           if(grid.$topPanel == null) // FIX ui-router
            return;

                grid.$topPanel.off('mousedown');

                if (grid.config.enableColumnReordering) {
                    grid.$topPanel.off('drop');
                }

                grid.$topPanel = null;
            });
```

Comment: This is indeed the fix and therefore the correct answer.

Comment: Thanks. Worked for me. Is this now added  in the latest version?

Answer (score 1):

I also found I needed to change the below (see Alex Choroshin post)

```
grid.$groupPanel.on('$destroy', function () {
                if (grid.$groupPanel == null) // FIX ui-router
                    return;

                grid.$groupPanel.off('mousedown');

                grid.$groupPanel = null;
            });
```

Its just a few lines above the recommended fix.

Answer (score -1):

I solved changing the order of jQuery dependency in my dependencies on index.html before the ui-router dependency.